# FirefoxDriver does not implement WebElement interface then how click method is accessible

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Here we are creating instance of FirefoxDriver class, and FirefoxDriver does not implement WebElement interface. As we know, `click()` method is defined in WebElement interface. so in statement below:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("some id")).click();
```

How is the `click()` method accessible here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`driver.findElement` returns `WebElement`. You can split the line to two instead of chaining the methods:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("some id"));
element.click();
```

For more information look [here](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html)